# PowerShell - Compare 2 Objects based and find mismatches

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have below 2 Objects which give me folder contents. (Not in Local windows file system but it's in Azure data lake)

```
$Gen1Files= $Folder1Details | select FilePath, FileLength

$Gen2Files= $Folder2Details | Select FilePath, FileLength
```

Folder1 is source and folder2 is target. After copying data to target, I want to compare both objects based on FilePath and need nice result exported to CSV that gives me results like file available, file missing, FileLength matches, FileLength Missing etc..

I have seen Compare-Object command but not sure if I can use it for this scenario. please help.

**Edit:**

I have written below code and its working correctly. But i feel the code is very lengthy and it can be rewritten. Any thoughts?

```
    ForEach ($Gen1File in $Gen1Files) {

        $Gen2Match = $Gen2Files | Where-Object { $_.Path -eq $Gen1File.Path } 
        If ($Gen2Match) {
            # Process the data
            if ($Gen1File.Length -eq $Gen2Match.Length) {
                $MatchResult += New-Object PsObject -Property @{Gen1FilePath = $Gen1File.Path; Gen2FilePath = $Gen2Match.Path; Gen1FileSize = $Gen1File.Length;
                    Gen2FileSize = $Gen2Match.Length; IsMatching = "Yes"
                }
            }

            else
            {
                $MatchResult += New-Object PsObject -Property @{Gen1FilePath = $Gen1File.Path; Gen2FilePath = $Gen2Match.Path; Gen1FileSize = $Gen1File.Length;
                    Gen2FileSize = $Gen2Match.Length; IsMatching = "No"
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            $MatchResult += New-Object PsObject -Property @{Gen1FilePath = $Gen1File.Path; Gen2FilePath = ""; Gen1FileSize = $Gen1File.Length;
                Gen2FileSize = ""; IsMatching = "No"
            }
        }
    }

# Check if Gen2 files are available in Gen1 Account 

    ForEach ($Gen2File in $Gen2Files) {

        $Gen1Match = $Gen1Files | Where-Object { $_.Path -eq $Gen2File.Path } 

        If ($Gen1Match) {
            # Process the data
            if ($Gen2File.Length -eq $Gen1Match.Length) {
                $MatchResult += New-Object PsObject -Property @{Gen1FilePath = $Gen1Match.Path; Gen2FilePath = $Gen2File.Path; Gen1FileSize = $Gen1Match.Length;
                    Gen2FileSize = $Gen2File.Length; IsMatching = "Yes"
                }
            }

            else
            {
                $MatchResult += New-Object PsObject -Property @{Gen1FilePath = $Gen1Match.Path; Gen2FilePath = $Gen2File.Path; Gen1FileSize = $Gen1Match.Length;
                    Gen2FileSize = $Gen2File.Length; IsMatching = "No"
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            $MatchResult += New-Object PsObject -Property @{Gen1FilePath = ""; Gen2FilePath = $Gen2File.Path; Gen1FileSize = "";
                Gen2FileSize = $Gen2File.Length; IsMatching = "No"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the complete script you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start, or it would at least help other people understand the question.  -passthru would just pass the original objects.  I'm sure there's other posts on comparing files in two folders.  There's a lot of confusion around compare-object.  Unless you're comparing strings, you probably need to specify the properties to compare.  Note that both lists will be sorted before comparing.

```
echo hi > gen1/same   
echo hi > gen2/same
echo hi > gen1/gen1only
echo hi > gen2/gen2only
echo hi > gen1/different
echo hihi > gen2/different

$a = dir gen1
$b = dir gen2

compare-object $a $b -property name,length -IncludeEqual # -passthru

name      length SideIndicator
----      ------ -------------
same           3 ==
different      5 =>
gen2only       3 =>
different      3 <=
gen1only       3 <=
```